# Playing Sound Effects while in Background Mode

Tags: iphone, audio, background

I have a need to play some sporadic sound effects in the background of an iPhone app.  From everything I've read and experienced with iOS 4, I can keep my app running in the background as long as I am running GPS by specifying "location" as a background mode.  That actually works.  But at times I want to play a sound effect...in other words, it's not "continuous" sound which I see reference to.

But the app is running, so why can't I just use AVAudioPlayer to play some sound effects?  Would another sound API work?

GAHHH!

```
    NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"BEEP" ofType:@"aiff"];
NSURL *fileURL = [[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: soundFilePath] autorelease];

AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];

player.volume = 1.0;
[player prepareToPlay];

// play
[player play];
```

Comment: Any more information on this one? I have set the relevant keys in the plist, and I can see in the debugger that the call to play the audio file is executed. I have also set the audio session for AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback and call the set the session to active using [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: &activationError]; 

No joy.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue  :/ Any idea or workaround ? :(

Comment: I'm able to get it running, see changes in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is important to clarify that your application is not running in the background. Rather, your application is 'put to sleep'. The `info.plist` background process value that you specify tells the OS that it should wake your application and allow it to respond to specific types of events. From the [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

> Each of the preceding values [audio, location, voip] lets the system know that your application should be woken up at appropriate times to respond to relevant events.

In your case, your application is frozen and is only able to respond to the type of event that you specify (location, or GPS).

You don't make it clear what context this code is in, so at this point it's difficult to tell you why the audio is not playing. Also, you need to make sure that your application is running in the background for the specified purpose. If you are using the `location` mechanism and not using GPS in your app, you may get rejected when you submit your application.

You may also want to refer to the [Checklist for Supporting Multitasking](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW1) to ensure the structure of your application implements their requirements.

Comment: What's it matter? I am calling AVAudioPlayer from a function I *know* is running, it shows the logs.

Comment: I should add my app really is doing GPS, it's a navigation app of sorts.  I want to fire sound effects when you get near certain landmarks.

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT]

<strike>You have a good example of background playback while monitoring GPS position here :</strike>

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1646438&seqNum=5

And it's using `AudioToolbox` rather than `AVAudioPlayer`

I've managed to do it using the **AVAudioPlayer**.

did you also add the `audio` value in the `info.plist` for key `UIBackgroundModes` ?

Answer (score -1):

The answer is that it won't work with AVAudioPlayer.  Use the AudioServicesPlaySystemSound API instead.

Comment: I used the AudioServicesPlaySystemSound API and get exactly the same beahvior :/ NSString* soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mySound" ofType:@"aiff"];
 SystemSoundID soundId = 1024;
 NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:soundPath];
 AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID ((CFURLRef)url, (SystemSoundID *)&soundId);
 AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundId);